# Typescript on Kendo UI - typed datasource definition

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

I am starting to migrate an application into Typescript that uses Kendo UI.

One of the first items that I believe I am not using typescript full potential is for the definition of the Datasource. While writing the datasource definition, I didn´t get any of the typed properties of the "transport" object (e.g. read, parameterMap, etc.).

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to define a datasource on typescript?

I went on Kendo's documentation but couldn't find any example that was written differently.

See my code below:

```
class ViewModel extends kendo.data.ObservableObject {
    dadosGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "jsonp",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/Controller/Action',
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options) {
                return kendo.stringify(options);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            total: "Total",
            data: "Data",
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" },
                    Surname: { type: "string" },
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    });

    //#endregion
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you reference the Kendo definitions file at the top of your TypeScript file?

```
/// <reference path="kendo.all.d.ts" />
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/howto/typescript/overview

Comment: Hi, yes I have. I am getting the types for other kendo widgets as well. I also get it for the kendo.data.Datasource type, and also a suggestion for when I type the "transport", but it stops there (no suggestion/intellisense for the "read" property for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I hit this as well.  This question is old, so just adding for anyone else.  I'm guessing they need to update their definition.  For now, I'm just doing something like this:

var dataSource: any = this._scheduler.dataSource;
   dataSource.transport.options.read.url = schedulerOptions.readUrl;

Comment: I believe that doing it the way you mentioned is worse than my approach because your datasource isn't typed at all. Anyway, kendo should do something about it because we lose the typesafe that TypeScript gives us...

Comment: After hitting this one again, I posted in their forum.  Telerik confirmed it is an issue, and they plan to add more to their typescript definition:  http://www.telerik.com/forums/datasource-typescript-definition-missing-info

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but still
You can use separate interface for it and use it like on screenshot
[image: screenshot]